# Why does -webkit-text-stroke look different on Chrome and Safari?

Tags: css, fonts, webkit, stroke

I'm trying to build a website but I've realised that the text stroke is a different weight between Chrome and Safari. On Chrome it's thick and on Safari it's really thin:

[image] 
[image]

How can I fix this so that they look the same on both browsers? When I try 1px onwards the stroke in Chrome is too thick.

```css
@media screen, (max-width: 1920px) and  {
    h1 { font-family: "Avant Garde", Avantgarde, "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
    font-size: 80px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-variant: normal;
    line-height: 26.4px; 
    color: transparent;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 120px;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
        
    
}

@supports(-webkit-text-stroke: 0.1px white){
    h1{
        color: transparent;
        -webkit-text-stroke: 0.1px white;
        text-shadow: 1px 1px #00FFD8, 1px 1px #00FFD8, 3px 3px #00FFD8;
}
    
h1 a{color: transparent;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0.1px white;
    text-shadow: 2px 2px #00FFD8, 1px 1px #00FFD8, 3px 3px #00FFD8;
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: letter-spacing 1s ease,
                text-shadow 0.5s ease; 
    
    
}

h1 a:hover {
color: transparent;
        -webkit-text-stroke: 0.1px white;
text-shadow: 1px 1px #9700FF, 1px 1px #9700FF, 6px 6px #9700FF;
    transition: letter-spacing 1s ease,
                text-shadow 0.5s ease; 
letter-spacing: 8px;
}
        
    }}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, minimum-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <title></title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
        
    </head>
    <body>

                <h1>
            <a href="main.html">hello</a> 
        </h1>      
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try to post the code here instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 2):

Without being able to mess with your code (I'm not going to retype it), I *think* the issue is not specifically related to `-webkit-text-stroke` but the fact that you're specifying a line width of less than a full pixel.

Chrome and Safari support subpixel rendering/smoothing differently as does your monitor's ability to display less than a full pixel.

Try setting the stroke width to `1px` and I'll bet they look the same.

---

The other issue is that `text-stroke` isn't part of the CSS spec so it's going to be supported differently in each instance. Also not all browsers (notably IE & Edge) support `text-stroke` so you can't count on it being available.

A better cross-browser solution would be to use multiple `text-shadows` to get the effect you're looking for.

Comment: Hi, just pasted the code thanks. I tried 1px and onwards, the stroke just gets thicker and not the same as each other on either browser. I will try text-shadows if need be.

Comment: Oh no, I just realised it's because Google Chrome isn't detecting the font Avant Garde but Safari is.

Answer (score 1):

Okay so after playing around with this for a while I think it's directly related to font-weight on Chrome, I had to manually set an entry for font-weight to 500 or less for it to appear accurately on Chrome as it does on other browsers.  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/-webkit-text-stroke) about: `-webkit-text-stroke`

> Non-standard: This feature is non-standard and is not on a standards track. Do not use it on production sites facing the Web: it will not work for every user. There may also be large incompatibilities between implementations and the behavior may change in the future.

Try using `text-shadow` instead as @Bryce said:

Using multiple `text-shadow` values can achieve the same effect: ([Credit](https://css-tricks.com/adding-stroke-to-web-text/))

```css
.text-stroke {
    color: white;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 1px black;
}

.text-shadow {
    font-weight: bolder; 
    color: white;
    text-shadow: 
        -1px -1px 0 black,
        -1px 1px 0 black,
        1px -1px 0 black,
        1px 1px 0 black;
}
```

```html
<p>Text Stroke Style: (will change based on browser)</p>
<h1 class='text-stroke'>1234567890</h1>

<p>Text-shadow Style:</p>
<h1 class='text-shadow'>1234567890</h1>
```